# mysql server error ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

I accidentally stopped the installation of mysql while setting the root password and now I can't, neither open the application, nor uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

returns

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 10071 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file, despite the warning.

Comment: before killing the process that is using it?  that can cause damage..

Comment: no you have to kill the process first if there is one. based on the comment that he stopped the installation, I don't think there is one.